# How to disable Magento 2 Content Security Policy with theme edit only

Tags: magento2, theme, magento2.4, security

I have searched alot on the internet and I want to hide this error (magento 2.4)
[image]

content security policy error , we don't have authority to disable magento_csp module and we can not create module, we just have theme, what are the best options to figure out this issue

Answer (score -1):

> **Please disable Magento_Csp module**

```
php bin/magento module:disable Magento_Csp

php bin/magento s:up

php bin/magento c:c
```

> **OR**

> Into **Magento_root/app/etc/config.php** find **Magento_Csp** and put 1 to 0 like this then save the file and run php bin/magento s:up
> command.

```
'Magento_Csp' => 0,
```

***I Hope This Helps You.***

Comment: bro disabling module is not an option i have explained that in the question , you can read again

Comment: Ok then you have to whitelist all files which are coming from 3rd party site or url.

Comment: You can google it how to whitelist in csp magento 2.4

Comment: i know how to whitelist it bro but disabling it with theme only is what i dont know , for that i have pasted the question

Comment: disable with theme what u by this?? its not possible man. you have to disable module or you have to whitelist file. no any other option :)

Comment: @samairali even if you find a way to manipulate the output of those messages through the theme the result will not be following best practice. This is not a theme level resolution.

Comment: Yes @dchayka . I also told them same thing.